# Speed up the VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

Do you know how I could speed up the running of the following VBA code? I've tried browsing online but there might be something else I'm missing here. It is a simple script and I'm surprised it takes a bit of time to run it. Thanks

```
Sub ExistingRecord()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim ButtonName As Variant
    Dim ButtonNames As Variant

    ButtonNames = Array("ButtonUpdateExisting", "ButtonAddNew", "ClearForm")
        Rows("2").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("3:22").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

        Range("D2").Select
          For Each ButtonName In ButtonNames
          ActiveSheet.Buttons("ButtonUpdateExisting").Visible = True
          ActiveSheet.Buttons("ButtonAddNew").Visible = False
          ActiveSheet.Buttons("ClearForm").Visible = True
        Next ButtonName

    ClearDataEntry

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: what is ClearDataEntry? and a minor syntax aspect is you don't have to select rows, you can instead do this `Rows("2").EntireRow.Hidden = False`

Comment: This is a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Remove the line `For Each ButtonName In ButtonNames` and the line `Next ButtonName`. You may also remove the line `ButtonNames = Array("ButtonUpdateExisting", "ButtonAddNew", "ClearForm")`. Also, `ClearDataEntry` calls another sub which we don't see. So, please include this code in your post so we can see if the problem lies within that procedure.

Comment: Hello all thanks so much for looking at this. I've been very busy over the last two days an I will look at all your comments over the weekend or next week. I am very grateful! Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at `ClearDataEntry`, it's difficult to see where this is slowing down. But the code above can be reduced to the following which should be quicker:

```
Sub ExistingRecord()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Rows("2").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("3:22").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    ActiveSheet.Buttons("ButtonUpdateExisting").Visible = True
    ActiveSheet.Buttons("ButtonAddNew").Visible = False
    ActiveSheet.Buttons("ClearForm").Visible = True

    ClearDataEntry

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```