# VBA Takes Too Long to Run

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Below code is just fine, the only problem is it takes too long to process.
Does anyone know how to speed it up?

```
Public Sub separate_line_break()

target_col = "H"     'Define the column you want to break
delimiter = Chr(10)   'Define your delimiter if it is not space
ColLastRow = Range(target_col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Rng In Range(target_col & "1" & ":" & target_col & ColLastRow)
    If InStr(Rng.Value, delimiter) Then
        Rng.EntireRow.Copy
        Rng.EntireRow.Insert
        Rng.Offset(-1, 0) = Mid(Rng.Value, 1, InStr(Rng.Value, delimiter) - 1)
        Rng.Value = Mid(Rng.Value, Len(Rng.Offset(-1, 0).Value) + 2, Len(Rng.Value))
    End If
Next

ColLastRow2 = Range(target_col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each Rng2 In Range(target_col & "1" & ":" & target_col & ColLastRow2)
    If Len(Rng2) = 0 Then
        Rng2.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

What I am trying to achieve is to split the data in column F based on the lines. You can see there some of the lines contains more than one lines (numbers).

I wanted to separate every line with number more that one to a new lines like shows at second image.

Can someone pls advise. Greatly appreciate your help. Thank you

Data after split:

[image: Data after split]

Data before split:

[image: Data before split]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speed up the VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42414167/speed-up-the-vba-code)

Comment: You can read the complete range into a variant array (`Arr=rng.value2`), do all operations within the array and write it back in one step. This should be WAY faster (I'd bet a factor of 100 or so). If you enconter problems with that, come back.

Comment: Hi Jochen, I am not a programmer, appreciate if you can help me modified the code. I found the code on the net and modified it my self, but dont know at all how to implement your advice.

Answer (score 0):

While using & to perform concatenation of different types of data is convenient, it also requires the machine to determine what types of data it is dealing with. This may not make much different but that largely depends on how much data the routine is handling.

So instead of

```
For Each Rng In Range(target_col & "1" & ":" & target_col & ColLastRow)
```

use

```
For Each Rng In Range(target_col + "1" + ":" + target_col + CStr(ColLastRow))
```

Also, don't concatenate literals. So instead of

```
For Each Rng In Range(target_col + "1" + ":" + target_col + CStr(ColLastRow))
```

use

```
For Each Rng In Range(target_col + "1:" + target_col + CStr(ColLastRow))
```

Dereferencing can be also be shortened somewhat using With/End With. The following change only deferences Rng once. Use the same methodology in the  Rng2 loop.

```
For Each Rng In Range(target_col + "1:" + target_col + CStr(ColLastRow))
    With Rng
        If InStr(.Value, delimiter) Then
            .EntireRow.Copy
            .EntireRow.Insert
            .Offset(-1, 0) = Mid(.Value, 1, InStr(.Value, delimiter) - 1)
            .Value = Mid(.Value, Len(.Offset(-1, 0).Value) + 2, Len(.Value))
        End If
    End With
Next
```

It also appears you loops will only iterate once, so you could do away with the loops all together.

```
With Range(target_col + "1:" + target_col + CStr(ColLastRow))
    If InStr(.Value, delimiter) Then
         .EntireRow.Copy
        .EntireRow.Insert
        .Offset(-1, 0) = Mid(.Value, 1, InStr(.Value, delimiter) - 1)
        .Value = Mid(.Value, Len(.Offset(-1, 0).Value) + 2, Len(.Value))
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your solution. It seems working. I can reduce from 20+ second to 13 second.
Buat i can't implement the last code.
it shows "Type mismatch" error.
Appreciate if you can come with the complete modified code. 
Thank you so much for your time.